# Pass a parameter to a event handler in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters

How I send to the handler a variable that's on the outer scope?

```
i = 1;
$(id).change(function() {myHandler(i)});
i = 2;
```

When called, the parameter is 2.

Also tried as string, that work in DOM but dont work in jQuery:

```
$(id).change('myHandler(' + i + ')');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Say you want to pass data object,

```
var data = {i: 2};
$(id).change(data, myHandler);
```

In the `myHandler` function:

```
function myHandler(event) {
    var i = event.data.i; // <= your data
}
```

The value passes as parameter if modified later wont get reflected.

Comment: *The value passes as parameter if modified later wont get reflected.* Probably only if you assign primitive values.

Comment: @FelixKling Probably yes. Agree!

Comment: cool, thanks.. just changed second parameter `function() {myHandler(i)}` to `myHandler`

Comment: Its good question and nice answer. And may I how can achive this to hover,toggle,.. events.. Like, $(elt).change(myHandler11,myHandler22); How can i pass object to these function handlers?!

Answer (score 1):

By calling a function that accepts i as an argument and returns a function, you can make a closure that traps the current value of i.

```
function changeHandlerClosure(i) {
    return function() {
        //do stuff here with i
    };
}

i = 1;
$(id).change(changeHandlerClosure(i));
i = 2;
```

This avoids interacting with the DOM, which is sometimes more convenient but slower.

Comment: Not the closure is capturing the current value, this is done by making the function call and creating a new scope through that. Though of course the function returned by `makeChangeHandler` is a closure...

Comment: this is nice but i believe the other method is better

Comment: Not quite Felix. The outer function forms a closure. The inner (returned) function becomes the actual event handler, which thanks to closure, still has access to `i` in the outer environment despite `changeHandlerClosure` having completed and returned.

Comment: No, you are confusing this. `makeChangeHandler` is *not* a closure in this situation, it does not close over any variable. The inner function, the one you return, is a closure, since it closes over `i`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29

Comment: Whoops, I called the function the wrong name, which was bound to confuse. Code edited.